# Merge elements of array with comma with max counter

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array of ids something like this:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
```

I need a function that will be called like ***mergeArray(arr, 3)***, and it should return comma separated values with maximum of 3 elements like this:

```
const newArr = ['1,2,3', '4,5,6', '7,8,9', '10,11'];
```

How can I do this? If possible with ES6 functions for simpler code.

Comment: What did you write ? What part was a problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

slice your array into 3 lengths arrays and directly join them

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];

const mergeArray = (arr, size) => {
  let res = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) { 
    res.push(arr.slice(i, i + size).join(','));
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(mergeArray(arr, 3));
```

Comment: Just please change your answer to be **i+size** in _arr.slice()_ instead of hard coded number 3

Answer (score 1):

You can [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the array into the specific size and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them before pushing into the resulting array:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];
var i, j, newArr=[], size = 3;
for (i=0,j=arr.length; i<j; i+=size) {
  newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i+size).join());
}
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do it is with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and  [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11];

function mergeArray(arr, n) {
    return arr
          .reduce((all, el, i) => {

              const ind = Math.floor(i/n);
              all[ind] = [...all[ind] || [], el]

              return all;

          },[])
          .map(a => a.join(','))
}

console.log(mergeArray(arr, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join the array and match the wanted parts with a regular expression.

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    result = data.join(',').match(/\d+(,\d+(,\d+)?)?/g)

console.log(result);
```